# How do I iterate over all my model attributes on my JSP page?

Tags: spring, jsp, input, jboss, model

I'm using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE with JBoss 7.1.3.Final and Java 6.  I have this method in a controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myMethod(final Model model,
                        final HttpServletRequest request,
                        final HttpServletResponse response,
                        final Principal principal) 

...
    model.addAttribute("paramName", "paramValue");
```

Notice how I add attributes into my model.  My question is, on the JSP page that this page serves, how do I iterate over all the attributes in my model and output them as HIDDEN input fields with the name of the INPUT being the attribute name and the value being what I inserted in the model using that attribute?

**Edit:** In response to the answer given, here was the output to the JSP solution.  Note there are no model attributes in there.

```
        <input type='hidden' name='javax.servlet.jsp.jspRequest' value='org.springframework.web.context.support.ContextExposingHttpServletRequest@7a0a4c3f'>

        <input type='hidden' name='javax.servlet.jsp.jspPageContext' value='org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl@3939794a'>

        <input type='hidden' name='appVersion' value='???application.version???'>

        <input type='hidden' name='javax.servlet.jsp.jspResponse' value='org.owasp.csrfguard.http.InterceptRedirectResponse@722033be'>

        <input type='hidden' name='javax.servlet.jsp.jspApplication' value='io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl@14c1252c'>

        <input type='hidden' name='org.apache.taglibs.standard.jsp.ImplicitObjects' value='javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ImplicitObjects@23c27a49'>

        <input type='hidden' name='javax.servlet.jsp.jspOut' value='org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl@b01a1ba'>

        <input type='hidden' name='javax.servlet.jsp.jspPage' value='org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.lti.launch_jsp@1dcc48bf'>

        <input type='hidden' name='javax.servlet.jsp.jspConfig' value='io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletConfigImpl@3fd40806'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model attributes are "request scope" objects
you can do the following (I use JSTL):

```
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope}" var="par">
        <c:if test="${par.key.indexOf('attrName_') > -1}">
            <li>${par.key} - ${par.value}</li>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
```

Since with no filter you will have all the request scope objects, I filtered by the model attributes we wanted to check

I tested by using this code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET }, value = { "/*" })
    public String renderPage(Model model) throws Exception
    {
        String requestedUrl = req.getRequestURI();
        int indice = requestedUrl.lastIndexOf('/');
        String pagina = requestedUrl.substring(indice + 1);
        try
        {
            String usernameUtente = "default username utente";
            if (StringUtils.hasText(getPrincipal()))
            {
                usernameUtente = getPrincipal();
            }
            model.addAttribute("usernameUtente", usernameUtente);
            model.addAttribute("webDebug", webDebug);
            for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
            {
                model.addAttribute("attrName_"+i, "attrValue_"+i);
            }
            return pagina;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String message = "Errore nell'erogazione della pagina " + pagina;
            logger.error(message, e);
            return "genericError";
        }
    }
```

And this is what I see as output (I omitted the not relevant prints but please note you'll print ALL the request scope objects:

```
attrName_0 - attrValue_0
attrName_1 - attrValue_1
attrName_2 - attrValue_2
attrName_3 - attrValue_3
attrName_4 - attrValue_4
attrName_5 - attrValue_5
attrName_6 - attrValue_6
attrName_7 - attrValue_7
attrName_8 - attrValue_8
attrName_9 - attrValue_9
```

I hope this can help

Angelo

Comment: THis looks real good.  ONe question, in your solution do all the attributes have to start with a special prefix in order for this to work?  What other junk will get printed to the page if I don't filter by a prefix?

Comment: Well all attributes have their own key; sadly I don't know all the attributes since some of them can be added by Application Server, others by the application framework (e.g. spring) and others by you... So the best thing maybe is to put a prefix to all your attributes and filter only for these ones

Comment: There's no way to know which ones were added by JBoss and Spring?

Comment: Well... honestly I don't know... I saw that spring always add them by using full qualified name but I'm not sure it is always so; regarding JBoss... I don't know at all

Answer (score 2):

For avoid headache with parameters added by Spring and Servlet container, it is better to use separate map for pass values into the model. Just use `@ModelAttribute` and Spring will create and add it to the model automatically:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myMethod(final Model model, @ModelAttribute("map") HashMap<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("paramName1", "value1");
    map.put("paramName2", "value2");
    //...and so on
}
```

Now you can iterate this map in JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${map.keySet()}" var="key">
    <input type="hidden" name="${key}" value="${map[key]}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Also you can access to every item of map next way:

```
<c:out value="${map.paramName1}"/>
<c:out value="${map.paramName2}"/>
...
```

If you don't need some parameter to be iterable, add it into the original `ModelMap` istead of separate map.

Answer (score 1):

In essence all you need is to itterate on all the page attributes. Depending on what you use on your jsp (scriptlets, jstl, or smthing like thymeleaf for html):

Scriptlet:

```
<form>
    <% Session session = request.getSession();
    Enumeration attributeNames = session.getAttributeNames();
    while (attributeNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = attributeNames.nextElement();
        String value = session.getAttribute(name);
    %>
        <input type='hidden' name="<% name %>" value="<% value %>">
    <%
        }
    %>
</form>
```

JSTL:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<h3>Page attributes:</h3>
<form>
    <c:forEach items="${pageScope}" var="p">
        <input type='hidden' name='${p.key}' value='${p.value}'>
    </c:forEach>
 </form>
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<form>
    <input th:each="var : ${#vars}" type='hidden' name="${var.key}" value="${var.value}">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried your JSTL solution (output included in my question).  I want to make sure you understand my question before I take any rash action.  I'm looking for model attributes.  What is output are not model attributes.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can iterate using **foreach** tag of Jstl.

```
 <c:forEach items="${requestScope}" var="var">
    <c:if test="${ !var.key.startsWith('javax.') && !var.key.startsWith('org.springframework')}">
        <input type="hidden" name="${var.key}" value="${var.value}" />
    </c:if>
 </c:forEach>
```

Request attributes from spring framework and from Servlet do have prefixes, you don't need to add prefix to your request attributes.

**Rather you can ignore all those attributes which have prefix "org.springframework" or "javax.".**

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myMethod(final Model model,
                        final HttpServletRequest request,
                        final HttpServletResponse response,
                        final Principal principal) 

...
    //Create list for param names and another list for param values
    List<String> paramNames = new ArrayList();
    List<String> paramValues = new ArrayList();
    paramNames.add("paramName1");
    paramValues.add("paramValue1");
    paramNames.add("paramName2");
    paramValues.add("paramValue2");
    //paramValue1 is the value corresponding to paramName1 and so on...
    //add as many param names and values as you need 
    ...
    //Then add both lists to the model
    model.addAttribute("paramNames", paramNames);
    model.addAttribute("paramValues", paramValues);
```

Then in the JSP, you can iterate over paramNames list, and use the varStatus.index  to get the index of current round of iteration and use it to pull the value of corresponding param value from the paramValues list. Like this -

```
 <form id='f' name='myform' method='POST' action='/path/to/servlet'>
   <c:forEach items="${paramNames}" var="paramName" varStatus="status">     
     <input type='hidden' name='${paramName}' value='${paramValues[status.index]}'>
   </c:forEach>
 </form>
```

You can add other input elements to the form as needed but the above should generate all the hidden input elements for each of your parameter that you set in the Model.

Comment: THis requires an additional data structure so taht every time I add a new model attribute I also have to add its param name to the new data structure is that right?

Comment: As shown in the answer above you will need to add the param name and param value in two separate lists. You only need to add those param name and values to the lists which you want to generate hidden input element for. Since you are adding those lists to the model attributes as shown above so you don't need to add the param names directly to model attributes. Try if the above example works for you at is shows how to do it and then how to iterate over the two lists to generate the input elements with hidden field type.

Comment: The idea is that I only have to add those name-value pairs once, in one place.  I want the hidden inputs to be exactly everything that is stored in my model.  If I'm going to maintain a separate list, I might as well just add a new input on the page every time I add something to my model.

Comment: Why have two lists? Why not just use a Map<String, String> as suggested in another answer.